# order data.table with dash in column name || error Error in .checkTypos - Perhaps you intended

Tags: r, data.table

create sample data.table

```
DT <- data.table("xx-g"=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
```

Order

```
DT[order(xx-g),]

error: Error in .checkTypos(e, names_x) :  Object 'xx' not found. Perhaps you intended xx-g
```

Tried as character

```
DT[order(as.character("xx-g")),]
```

Use column name in quotes

```
DT[order("xx-g"),]
```

provide column name in variable

```
colvars<-"xx-g"

 DT[order(colvars),]
```

I cannot get this operational. Would be thankful if someone can provide pointer.

data.table_1.13.0
R 4.0 and windows 10 platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R you always need to use backticks `` when the name isn't regular, or use the `get` function or eval-as.name

```r
DT[order(`xx-g`),]
DT[order(get("xx-g")),]
DT[order(eval(as.name("xx-g"))),]
   xx-g y v
1:    a 1 4
2:    a 3 5
3:    a 6 6
4:    b 1 1
5:    b 3 2
6:    b 6 3
7:    c 1 7
8:    c 3 8
9:    c 6 9
```

Answer (score 1):

We can specify the column in `.SDcols`

```
DT[DT[, order(.SD[1]), .SDcols = 'xx-g']]
```